# What grub modules are necessary to boot from LVM on a DOS partition?

Tags: boot, grub2, lvm

I am trying to make my Ubuntu machine boot from a `/boot` LVM, and it seems that the default `core.img` does not support LVM, so I am trying to figure out what modules I need to supply to `grub-mkimage` in order to make it find my `/boot`. So far no luck -- `core_lvm.img` either becomes too big (> 32k) or does not actually see my LVM vg.

Example:

```
grub-mkimage -P i386-pc -o /boot/grub/core_lvm.img part_msdos ext2 lvm
grub-setup -c core_lvm '(hd0)'
```

Upon boot this gets me into a rescue prompt where I can only see `(hd0-*)`, not my LVM vg. What other modules do I need for LVM to work?

I'm continuing to experiment with this, but it would be great if someone has already done this and could tell me why the above is not enough for it to work.

Comment: Are you sure you have lvm2 installed?

Comment: It is GRUB that cannot manage to see the partitions, not the initrd. The initrd works. Currently I am working around this by booting from a /boot partition, but it would be neat to eliminate that.

Comment: Did you run `insmod lvm` on the Grub command line? Then do something like `set root=lvm/lvm_group_name-lvm_logical_boot_partition_name`. Please post your Grub configuration and read [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2#LVM). :)

Comment: `insmod lvm` on the Grub command line does not work as any modules would be ... on the LVM /boot partition. :-)

Comment: That Arch wiki page on Grub is a great read.

Comment: Ok, I have just learned from the source that grub-install actually creates core.img based on partition and filesystem that /boot/grub resides on. That means this should all *just work*. It doesn't.

Comment: Also `biosdisk` seems like an important module. I solved this somewhere else lately with `normal part_msdos ext2 lvm biosdisk`, but that image is huge. Worked in that case though, because it was not going to be embedded in the MBR, just loaded by GRUB4DOS.

Comment: Also, in that case, I embedded a pointer to the initial grub.cfg and grub root, so that it would find the correct version of grub modules etc. Still going to evaluate the `-c` option mentioned in @clover's answer at some point.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to prepare and embed  small `early-grub.cfg` file into `core.img` (`grub-mkimage -c early-grub.cfg`). It should set proper `root` and `prefix` variables and call `configfile $prefix/grub.cfg`. Example:

```
set root=lvm/lvm_group_name-lvm_logical_boot_partition_name
set prefix=($root)/boot/grub
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Also note, `grub-mkimage` automatically track dependant modules.

Comment: Aha, interesting! Will take a look at this. If it works, I will set your answer as the accepted one. There is probably a badge for getting an answer accepted a whole year after the question was originally asked. :-)

Comment: Where is the lines you wrote should I execute or place? Is it a shell command or content of config file?